# Is this matrix exponential strictly positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Is it true that $e^{Nt}$ is strictly positive element-wise, where $t>0$ and $N$ is a real matrix with $N_{ij}\geq0$ if $i\neq j$ and $N_{ij}\leq 0$ if $i=j$?

Answer (score 1):

**No this is not true**

Take for a counterexample

$$N = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Many thanks!  What if we add the restriction that each column sum of $N$ must be non-positive, i.e., $\sum_{i} N_{ij}\leq 0\;\forall j$

Comment: @Confinement that is another question. I suggest that you accept the answer to current question and open another one.